# How to get system to shutdown when Xorg is quit?

Tags: debian, xorg, shutdown

I installed `nodm`, so that Debian starts Xorg and a window manager immediately after booting, without requesting any password and without a login.

How can I similarly setup Debian to shutdown the system automatically, without password prompt, whenever the window manager and Xorg are quit?

Comment: You'd have to somehow monitor the `xorg` server/daemon and run `shutdown` when it quits. As to how you go about this, I don't know. Perhaps something in an X config file could issue that command on termination. Perhaps even in `~/.bash_logout` (assuming the default user for `nodm` is logged out when `xorg` quits).

Comment: I think you will find varying avenues based on how the system is shutdown. If a window-manager application is doing it, there will be fewer places to look for a script that can be tuned. If procs are being shutdown by a hot-key or even command line, different options available.

Answer (score 0):

Use a displaymanager, which supports scripts like `Xreset` and `Xsession`, for example kdm and configure it for auto login.

```
$ head -n5 /etc/kde4/kdm/Xreset 
#! /bin/sh
# Xreset - run as root after session exits

# Reassign ownership of the console to root, this should disallow
# assignment of console output to any random users's xterm. See Xstartup.
```

There you can place the shutdown command. Have a look at lightdm, maybe even xdm, if they support such scripts, too. maybe even nodm does.

Comment: `nodm` runs the user session using `Xsession` script; I haven't specifically checked its reset behaviour, but I'd be surprised if this didn't work.